# Angular - How to display single "no results" message on no results

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to show my "no results" div element. Basically, I have a list component containg order timeline section components, each one of these section contains order components. Like so:

[image]

My **orders-list.component.html** (check bottom div):

```
<div class="list-container" [ngClass]="{section: isDeliverySlotsActive === false}">
    <label class="list-header" *ngIf="isDeliverySlotsActive === true" style="margin-top: 1.625rem">DELIVERY SLOTS ORDERS</label>
    <div [ngClass]="{section: isDeliverySlotsActive === true}" *ngFor="let date of timelines">
        <app-orders-list-section
            [orders]="orders"
            [timeline]="date"
            [isDeliverySlotsActive]="isDeliverySlotsActive"
            [searchTerm]="searchTerm"
        ></app-orders-list-section>
    </div>
</div>
/* I want to show the below div when there are no results for the search */
<div id="no-results">
    <img src="../../../assets/my-orders/no-results.png" alt="No Results" style="margin-top: 6.063rem; margin-bottom: 2.837rem;">
    <label class="no-results-text">COULDN'T FIND ANYTHING</label>
    <label class="no-results-text weight-medium">Search by order number or customer</label>
</div>
```

For each section, a filtering method is applied when the user searches for an order using the search bar. If the search term does not correspond to an order in a section, the order is not displayed for that section. If there are no results for that section the section header is also not displayed.

My **orders-list-section.component.html**:

```
<div *ngIf="filteredSectionOrders.length > 0">
    <label
        *ngIf="isDeliverySlotsActive === true"
        [ngClass]="{ slots: isDeliverySlotsActive === true }">
    {{ timeline | addSectionDateFormat }}
    </label>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let order of filteredSectionOrders">
    <app-orders-list-item
        [order]="order"
        [timeline]="timeline"
    ></app-orders-list-item>
</div>
```

My filter method in the section component:

```
filterSectionOrders(searchString: string){
    if(!searchString) return;
    if(this.hasNumbers(searchString)){
        this.filteredSectionOrders = this.filteredSectionOrders.filter(order => order.order_num.toString().indexOf(searchString) !== -1);
    }
    else{
        this.filteredSectionOrders = this.filteredSectionOrders.filter(order => {
            if(order.first_name && order.last_name){
                let fullName = order.first_name + " " + order.last_name;
                if(fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                    return order;
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Given that I apply this filter to each section and not to the list as a whole, how can I find out when there are 0 total results so I can show **only one** (not for each section) div element with a "no results found" message?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This will be a lot easier if you run your filtering code in the parent component, prior to returning JSX. You can put each section into an ordered array, and have each of those arrays contain a subarray with the orders. It's good to do this in a React.useMemo() function for performance.

Comment: @Aadmaa Even though this isn't React, the approach of moving up the filtering logic to the parent component is still the correct one. If you want you can post your answer updated accordingly and I'll mark it as being the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: Corrected: you can run your filtering code in the parent component. You can put each section into an ordered array, and have each of those arrays contain a subarray with the orders. It's probably good to memoize this if possible for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `*ngIf;else` [link to ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) from angular inside your HTML

I am not sure where do you use `filteredSectionOrders`, because it is not shown in your html, but let's assume your `app-orders-list-section` has some HTML logic where you use `*ngFor` to loop through orders and show it properly

so, I guess your code looks something like this

```html
<div class="order" *ngFor="let order of filteredSectionOrders">
  <img/>
  <p>
    {{ order.first_name + ' ' + order.last_name }}
  </p>
</div>
```

This is simplified html how I assume it looks like.

What you can do is next:

```html
<ng-template *ngIf="filteredSectionOrders.length > 0; else noResultsBlock">
  // here you insert your code to render orders
  <div class="order" *ngFor="let order of filteredSectionOrders">
    <img/>
    <p>
      {{ order.first_name + ' ' + order.last_name }}
    </p>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #noResultsBlock>
  <p> No results </p>
</ng-template>
```

So, this would simple solution
If you want to improve it even more, it would be better to have a new variable, lets say `areThereResults`, which you will set to `true` or `false`, at the end of your method `filterSectionOrders`, based on `filterSectionOrders.length`. Then, you would use this new variable inside `*ngIf` check, instead of `filterSectionOrders.length > 0`.

Reason for using `boolean` variable instead of using actual array is detection changes, and will anguar re-render UI inside `*ngIf`. You can read more about it on Angular documentation, just search for detection changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I haven't tried your code yet, but judging from what I can see, your solution would show a "no results" message in each section, when it does not contain orders for the search term, correct? The thing is, and I should have been more clear, I only want to show **one** "no results" message (see the bottom div in the list component .html), not one for each section. Also, I updated my question.

Comment: I solved it by moving the filtering logic to the parent list component. This way I can send a filtered order array for the sections and, if this array is empty, I then display the "no results" prompt. Thanks again for your answer, it helped me figuring this out.